# opensource web builder(drag drop) tool supporting WYSIWYG for java web developers

Tags: user-interface, jakarta-ee, web, wysiwyg

I am java developer and I have to develop a dynamic web application in java, can anyone suggest me a **drag and drop tool(WYSIWYG)** for designing my website with jquery and ajax support, so that I dont have to spend more time on static coding.

**my platform:** *linux mint 13 64bit, sun jdk7, netbeans7*

thanx in advance..

Answer (score 4):

You will probably be interested by GWT.

[GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) is a platform in which you mainly code in java but which produces ajax based web applications.

Have a look at the [GWT Designer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/).

Comment: what about jquery effects and css styling in GWT, can it be done there.

Comment: GWT does the component management for you, so you normally don't have to use jquery. There is [this](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) but I don't know what it's worth.

Comment: can u please suggest me reference and good updated books for learning GWT.

Comment: I don't know books about GWT but [GWT's online documentation](https://developers.google.com/) is very good and contains tutorials.